# SQL Lite Data Types - C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am doing some basic SQL Lite database work via a C# application. I have followed the tutorial [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/) and have the basics working with no problem whatsoever. However, the database I am working with has some UNIX timestamps in it. I am looking to convert these to standard time. This again I have completed with no problem by simply adding the seconds onto the UNIX start time (1/1/1970).

However, my problem comes when I wish to cast this data back to a dataGridView. As the data has already been inserted into the grid view it has clearly formated the time column as an Int64 (from the UNIX seconds value) but I am trying to cast a DateTime value back to it thus resulting in an error.

Even if I amend the data before casting it to the dataGridView I still get this error which suggests there is something further going on here behind the scenes. I would assume that the way I am querying the DB is also bringing back this formatting.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: please post the query you are using to select data, and also how are you binding the data to the dataGridView

Comment: Full query code here -  `String query = "select value1 \"Header1\", value2 \"Header2\", value3 \"Header3\", timestamp \"Time\" from Table";`

`Messages = db.GetDataTable(query);`
         
`dataGridView1.DataSource = Messages;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting the unix timestamp in C#, you can use [SQLite DateTime Function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and then bind it to the datagridview

```
SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch');
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried this method but It came up with an incorrect syntax error. This is what I had tried - `"select datetime(timestamp , 'unixepoch')\"Time\" from Table";`

Comment: @BenCollins, I think you need to use single quotes not double with "Time" it should be `string myquery = @"select datetime(timestamp , 'unixepoch') 'Time' from Table";`

Comment: Time is the column name that I am giving to the Data Grid View. timestamp is the field from the DB that I am pulling out.

Comment: Fixed it like this `datetime(timestamp , 'unixepoch') \"Time\"`. Appreciate your help :)